# jquery select option dynamically assign value to another 2 input text

Tags: jquery, events

im trying to make simple change inputfield dynamically based on select option event change.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#opt_jendit').change(function(){

var jendit = $('#opt_jendit').val();

if(jendit='MBD'){
$("#txt_jenkre").val('KUM');
}

if(jendit='MBG.TKR'){
$("#txt_jenkre").val('KUR');
}

$("#txt_kodpk").val(jendit);

});
</script>
```

seems 2nd inputfield can't listen, the changes that occur in 1rst inputfield
[plese check this..](http://www.tengkuruk.tk/), im wondering, how the simple way to achive it ?

Comment: `=` assigns a value. `==` / `===` **compares** values. Please provide a [mcve], it's unclear what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: do you check the link above ?, i already give example on that link..

Comment: did you try `$("#txt_kodpk").text(jendit);` ?

Comment: All relevant information should be contained in the post itself, not on some external site. [You can add runnable examples to your post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: atA.Lau : still not working dear.. atFelix: thanks for advice, ill try provide to you

Comment: So I just tried $("#txt_kodpk").val('hi'); and it worked. Check if jendit actually has value?

Comment: atLau and atFelix: resolved by Qaeed Ramiwala, thanks mate for give me a hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, your `if` condition was incorrect with `=` instead it should be `==`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#opt_jendit').change(function() {

    var jendit = $('#opt_jendit').val();
    
    $("#txt_kodpk").val(jendit);
    if (jendit == 'MBD') {
      $("#txt_jenkre").val('KUM');
    } else if (jendit == 'MBG.TKR'){
            $("#txt_jenkre").val('KUR');
    }
     else{
        $("#txt_jenkre").val("");
    }
 });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-6">

  <div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control" name="opt_jendit" id="opt_jendit">
      <option value="" selected="">--PILIH PRODUK PINJAMAN--</option>
      <option value="MBD">Kredit Usaha Mikro [ KUM ]</option>
      <option value="MBG.TKR">Kredit Usaha Rakyat [ KUR ]</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Kode PK" name="txt_kodpk" id="txt_kodpk" type="text">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Jenis Kredit" name="txt_jenkre" id="txt_jenkre" type="text">
  </div>
  <div>
```

Comment: atQaeed Ramiwala : its worked , thanks , but in my workspace if we choose first option [default] after selecting option cannot back to default position like in your snippet.

Comment: @ariowishnu try updated answer. Now it will reset on default. If it helps please upvote :)

Comment: @Qaeed Ramiwala :bahut bahut dhanyavaad, meree madad kee, thankss , btw i already give upvote but why it cannot change to 1 ?

Comment: @ariowishnu insufficient reputation.